# positioning multiple divs inside a container

Tags: html, css

This seems pretty easy but it's just not going where I want it to.

I need to position 3 of the divs left, and 1 right, but the one I need on the right doesn't go all the way over to the edge of the page.

I need the .pic1 left, .info1 left of that, .desc1 left (but underneath .desc1) and .price1 far right.

```
<div class="gtr1">
    <div class="pic1">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['img'])?>"alt="This image cannot be found or has been removed." width="150" height="200">

    </div>
    <div class="info1">
        <p>
        <?php echo $row['name'] ?>  
        </p>
    </div>

            <div class="desc1">
        <p> 
            <?php echo $row['description'] ?>
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class="price1">
        <p>
            $<?php echo $row['price'] ?> 
            <br>
            <br>
            <!-- This is correct now -->
            <a href="cart.php?add=<?php echo $row['id_product'] ?>">Add to cart</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I'm working on so far with CSS

```
.gtr1 {
float: left;
//*border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);*//
width: 100%;
}
.pic1 {
float: left;

}
.info1 {
float: left;
padding-left: 50px;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
font-size: 12px ;
/*width: 400px ;*/
width:25%;

}

    .desc1 {
float: left;
margin: 0;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
padding-left: 50px ;
width: 45%

}

    .price1 {
float: right;
padding-right: 5px;
color: #FF0000 ;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0;
width:10%;
}

.price1 p {
float: right;
}
```

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: can you please provide any image

Answer (score 1):

Try putting clear: right; or clear: both; in the CSS of the one that you want to go to the right.
Also 1 more thing if you want to have all of them fit on the same axis. You should play around with the widths to make sure the width = 100% for all of them together.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to solve this is to put the `div` that you are floating right at the top of the container.

```html
<div class="gtr1">
  <div class="price1">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="pic1">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="info1">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="desc1">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```